# will a plot shown in VS code run from AWS Studio Lab

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, debugging

will be plot shown in VS code run from AWS Studio Lab FOR PLAIN PYTHON CODE FILE (NO JUPYTER NOTEBOOK USE)
if VS code was run as in
https://medium.com/codex/running-vs-code-for-free-on-aws-bfb1aed7be6f

for example we set break point at line number 123
run python code till this breakpoint
then write code in debugging window of terminal

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15)) 
plt.plot( [1,2,3,4,5], 'r', label='actual - reference')
plt.plot( [1.2,2.6,2.8,4.2,5.1],'b', label='predicted ')
plt.legend() 
plt.title("vowpal wabbit predictions2") 
plt.show(block=False)
```

then we want to see plot on computer screen and if needed to zoom this plot - we want interactive plot as full experience coding on local computer ?

Answer (score 0):

For interactivity, you should install [`ipympl`](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) library in your conda environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
```

This library allows you to add interactivity, as moving axes and zoom, to plots made inside jupyter notebooks, which you can run in VS code. Make sure you installed the jupyter and Python plugins for VS code

In your notebook, you have to use the `%matplotlib widget` magic function to show the plot interactively.

[image]